# how I could create a metaclass that work with string ; numbers and null values

Tags: groovy, metaclass

a metaclass that works with number value string value and null value

like this code ; please help me

```
String.metaClass.formatx = { delegate.toString().replaceAll(/null/, '0.0').toFloat() }


m= "4".formatx()

m2=4.formatx()
m3=null.formatx()
```

Comment: What should it do with null?!

Comment: use this function with the null value .toString().replaceAll(/null/, '0.0').toFloat()

Comment: convert to string replace null string by 0.0 and convert to float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd do the following:

```
String.metaClass.formatx = { -> delegate.toFloat() }

String a = "3"
String b = null

assert 3.0f == (a?.formatx() ?: 0.0f)
assert 0.0f == (b?.formatx() ?: 0.0f)
```

That is, defend against `null` in your code with `?.` and `?:`

If you *have* to try and catch the `null`, and format it, you *could* do:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject

String.metaClass.formatx = { -> delegate.toFloat() }
NullObject.metaClass.formatx = { -> 0.0f }

String a = "3"
String b = null

assert 3.0f == a.formatx()
assert 0.0f == b.formatx()
```

But adding a method to `NullObject` feels wrong, and I've never done it before

#### Edit

This is shorter

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject

[String, Integer].each { it.metaClass.formatx = { -> delegate.toFloat() } }
NullObject.metaClass.formatx = { -> 0.0f }

println null.formatx()
println 3.formatx()
println "4".formatx()
```

Comment: this works very thankyou for your help ; but not exist other way to do this with less code?

Answer (score 0):

I put this for example but I think THat I use much code

I repeat metaClass.formatx  three times ; I dont know if is possible use OR setences INSTEAD

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject

String.metaClass.formatx = { -> delegate.toString().replaceAll(/null/, '0.0').toFloat()  }
 NullObject.metaClass.formatx = { -> delegate.toString().replaceAll(/null/, '0.0').toFloat() }
Integer.metaClass.formatx = { -> delegate.toString().replaceAll(/null/, '0.0').toFloat() }

m2= 4.formatx()
m= "4".formatx()

 println null.formatx()
```

edit

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject



[String, Integer,NullObject].each { it.metaClass.formatx = { ->  delegate.toString().replaceAll(/null/, '0.0').toFloat()    } }

m2= 4.formatx()
m= "4".formatx()

 println null.formatx()
```

Comment: See the edit to my question about how to do it shorter than you have it...  My feelings of unease around `NullObject` remain however